# Interest of using activeMQ resource adapter

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

I am creating a Java application in eclipse to let different devices communicate together using a publish/subscribe protocol.

I am using Jboss and ActiveMQ and  I want to know if I should use an ActiveMQ resource adapter to integrate the broker in jboss in a standalone mode or I should just add dependencies in my pom.xml file and use explicit java code like indicated here  http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html.

Here the documentation I found to integrate ActiveMQ within jboss in a standalone mode https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.1/html/Integrating_with_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/DeployRar-InstallRar.html

Could someone tell me what is the difference between the two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for my question:

The first approach starts a broker within your webapp itself. You can use a 
normal consumer (not a message-driven bean - MDB), but only your webapp can 
access it, via the VM transport (vm://).

The second approach lets the app server manage both the connection to the 
broker and the creation of the broker, so it's probably also within the JVM 
that runs your webapp and probably only accessible to your webapp, but 
those details are hidden from you by the app server. You can only consume 
messages via an MDB, but this provides a uniform interface that doesn't 
need to change if you switch to another JMS provider in the future.

Since the standard way to integrate a JEE webapp with a JMS broker is via 
the RA, I'd recommend using that approach simply for consistency and 
standardization. That should also allow you to switch to a standalone 
ActiveMQ broker (or another JMS product) in the future with minimal effort.